# How to deserialise anonymous array of mixed types with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, strava

In my `Java` program, I am trying to parse data that I get from [Strava.com](https://strava.com)'s API. One of the `JSON` payloads, I receive from there looks as follows:

```
[
  {"type": "altitude","data": [519.1,519.3,519.3,519.4,519.5],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  {"type": "latlng","data": [[46.01234,6.01234],[46.11234,6.11234],[46.21234,6.21234],[46.31234,6.31234],[46.41234,6.41234]],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  {"type": "velocity_smooth","data": [0.0,0.0,0.0,5.5,5.2],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  {"type": "distance","data": [0.0,8.6,11.8,16.6,20.8],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  {"type": "time","data": [0,1,2,3,4],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"}
]
```

Basically, four of these entries (altitude, velocity_smooth, distance and time) have the same structure (their `data` field is an array of doubles (or ints that can be parsed as doubles)), but the second entry (latlng) has a slighlty different structure for the `data` field (it is a an array of arrays of double).

I am familiar with the `Jackson` library to convert between `JSON` and `POJO`s if all the content is named, but do not see how I can model the above data structure to deserialise it.

Let's say that instead of the data above, it looked as follows:

```
{
  "altitude": {"data": [519.1,519.3,519.3,519.4,519.5],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  "latlng":  {"data": [[46.01234,6.01234],[46.11234,6.11234],[46.21234,6.21234],[46.31234,6.31234],[46.41234,6.41234]],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  "velocity_smooth": {"data": [0.0,0.0,0.0,5.5,5.2],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  "distance":  {"data": [0.0,8.6,11.8,16.6,20.8],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"},
  "time": {"data": [0,1,2,3,4],"series_type": "distance","original_size": 5,"resolution": "high"}
}
```

Then I could define the following three classes

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Value;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Holder {
  DoubleData altitude;
  CoordinateData latlng;
  @JsonProperty("velocity_smooth") DoubleData velocitySmooth;
  DoubleData distance;
  DoubleData time;
}

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DoubleData {
  List<Double> data;
  @JsonProperty("series_type")   String seriesType;
  @JsonProperty("original_size") Integer originalSize;
  String resolution;
}

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CoordinateData {
  List<List<Double>> data;
  @JsonProperty("series_type")   String seriesType;
  @JsonProperty("original_size") Integer originalSize;
  String resolution;
}
```

And then use

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Holder.class);
```

to read in that object. However, as the data received from Strava is an array instead of an object, I am failing. I have read [Baeldung's article on how to unmarshal to collections/arrays](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array) but that assumes that all classes in the array/collection are the same.

I though about defining an interface which would be extended by the two classes that could be found in the array and then use that mechanism:

```
public interface Data {
}

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DoubleData implements Data {
  String type;
  List<Double> data;
  @JsonProperty("series_type")   String seriesType;
  @JsonProperty("original_size") Integer originalSize;
  String resolution;
}

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CoordinateData implements Data {
  String type;
  List<List<Double>> data;
  @JsonProperty("series_type")   String seriesType;
  @JsonProperty("original_size") Integer originalSize;
  String resolution;
}

Data[] array = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Data[].class);
```

But that doesn't work, as I would need to find some way to let it find out when to use a `DoubleData` class and when to use a `CoordinateData` class.

I am sure, I am not the first person trying to use Strava data in `Java`. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible, you should definitely use their's client. [Strava API v3](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/) shows many examples how to use this `API` together with theirs model.

If you want to implement your own model you should consider inheritance and `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo`, `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes` annotations. Also, `JSON Object` with type `latlng` contains list of objects which are represented in `JSON` in form of `array`. We can handle this using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` annotation. All together gives:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class StravaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.readValue(jsonFile, new TypeReference<List<Data>>() {}).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        visible = true,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "altitude", value = DoubleData.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "latlng", value = CoordinateData.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "velocity_smooth", value = DoubleData.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "distance", value = DoubleData.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "time", value = DoubleData.class)
})
abstract class Data<T> {

    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("series_type")
    private String seriesType;

    @JsonProperty("original_size")
    private Integer originalSize;

    private String resolution;

    private List<T> data;

    // getters, setters, toString
}


class DoubleData extends Data<Double> {

}

class CoordinateData extends Data<Coordinates> {

}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
class Coordinates {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

        // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Data[type='altitude', seriesType='distance', originalSize=5, resolution='high', data=[519.1, 519.3, 519.3, 519.4, 519.5]]
Data[type='latlng', seriesType='distance', originalSize=5, resolution='high', data=[Coordinates[lat=46.01234, lng=6.01234], Coordinates[lat=46.11234, lng=6.11234], Coordinates[lat=46.21234, lng=6.21234], Coordinates[lat=46.31234, lng=6.31234], Coordinates[lat=46.41234, lng=6.41234]]]
Data[type='velocity_smooth', seriesType='distance', originalSize=5, resolution='high', data=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.5, 5.2]]
Data[type='distance', seriesType='distance', originalSize=5, resolution='high', data=[0.0, 8.6, 11.8, 16.6, 20.8]]
Data[type='time', seriesType='distance', originalSize=5, resolution='high', data=[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

You should also take a look on [Google Dev Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/strava-api) and consult this solution.

Comment: I had seen their examples on the Strava API V3 page. I briefly tried to find out which maven dependency I would need to make use of it but failed to find that information on their page (though I did find some other projects). However, I really wanted this as an opportunity to learn how to deal with this myself, so thank you for your solution!