# How do I map a heterogeneous JSON array to a Java object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've downloaded a large amount of historic crypto market data via an API. It is formatted like this:

```
[
[1601510400000,"4.15540000","4.16450000","4.15010000","4.15030000","4483.01000000",1601510459999,"18646.50051400",50,"2943.27000000","12241.83706500","0"],
...
[1609490340000,"4.94020000","4.95970000","4.93880000","4.94950000","5307.62000000",1609490399999,"26280.03711000",98,"3751.46000000","18574.22402400","0"]
]
```

I take that to be an array of arrays, the inner one containing heterogeneous types (always the same types in the same order). As an intermediate step I've saved it to text files but I'd like to read it back and map it onto an array of objects of this type:

```
    public class MinuteCandle {
        private long openTime;
        private double openValue;
        private double highValue;
        private double lowValue;
        private double closeValue;
        private double volume;
        private long closeTime;
        private double quoteAssetVolume;
        private int numberOfTrades;
        private double takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;
        private double takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;
        private double someGarbageData;
//...
}
```

I'm using the Spring Framework and the jackson library for json mapping. Is it doable with that or should I manually parse the text somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JsonFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) and annotate your class with it where you specify shape as an `ARRAY`:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
class MinuteCandle
```

Also, consider to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` if you want to store a price.

See also:

- [A realistic example where using BigDecimal for currency is strictly
  better than using double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871564/a-realistic-example-where-using-bigdecimal-for-currency-is-strictly-better-than/44672401#44672401)
- [How to deserialise anonymous array of mixed types with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529882/how-to-deserialise-anonymous-array-of-mixed-types-with-jackson/61534666#61534666)

Comment: Wow, this works, too, and is simpler than Thomas' solution. I didn't think Jackson would know which fields to map to but obviously it simply does that from top to bottom. Also, thanks for recommending BigDecimal for prices. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in two steps:

1. Read the JSON content into a list of `List<Object>` with Jackson.
2. Convert each `List<Object>` into a `MinuteCandle` object
   and collect these objects into a list of `MinuteCandle`s.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File file = new File("example.json");
        List<List<Object>> lists = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<List<Object>>>() {});
        List<MinuteCandle> minuteCandles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Object> list : lists) {
            minuteCandles.add(MinuteCandle.createFromList(list));
        }
    }
}
```

The conversion from `List<Object>` to `MinuteCandle` (step 2 from above)
could be achieved by adding a static method in your `MinuteCandle` class.

```
public static MinuteCandle createFromList(List<Object> list) {
    MinuteCandle m = new MinuteCandle();
    m.openTime = (Long) list.get(0);
    m.openValue = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(1));
    m.highValue = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(2));
    m.lowValue = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(3));
    m.closeValue = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(4));
    m.volume = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(5));
    m.closeTime = (Long) list.get(6);
    m.quoteAssetVolume = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(7));
    m.numberOfTrades = (Integer) list.get(8);
    m.takerBuyBaseAssetVolume = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(9));
    m.takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(10));
    m.someGarbageData = Double.parseDouble((String) list.get(11));
    return m;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks. `new TypeReference<List<List<Object>>>()` can be replaced with `new TypeReference<>()`. I might end up using an array instead of an arraylist, as it will never need to change size and I'll be running costly calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text stored in the file is valid JSON, similar to the solution in  [How to Read JSON data from txt file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638765/how-to-read-json-data-from-txt-file-in-java) one can use `com.google.gson.Gson` as follows :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("somefile.txt")) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            MinuteCandle[] features = gson.fromJson(reader, MinuteCandle[].class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I doubt it could be that simple. Tried it, though, and got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0]"